# React onClick event does not work on map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on React and I'm rendering a table with the `map` function, this is the code in question:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => alert(":v")}>:v</button>
            <table id="tUsuarios" className="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th data-sortable="true">ID</th>
                        <th data-sortable="true">Nombre</th>
                        <th data-sortable="true">No. Empleado</th>
                        <th>Correo</th>
                        <th>Puesto</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {
                        this.state.usuarios.map(user =>
                                <tr key={user.User}>
                                    <td>{user.User}</td>
                                    <td>{user.Name}</td>
                                    <td>{user.Empleado}</td>
                                    <td>{user.Mail}</td>
                                    <td>{user.Puesto}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href={"/Usuario?u=" + user.User} title={"Perfil de " + user.Name}><span className="fa fa-user fa-lg"></span></a>
                                        &nbsp;
                                        <a href="#" onClick={() => alert(":v")}><span className="fa fa-edit fa-lg"></span></a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>)
                        })
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
}
```

While the button on top does the alert, any of the buttons inside `this.state.usuarios.map` fires the `onClick` event. This is the simplest thing (passing directly an `alert`) but even this is failling so hard. Does anyone have a clue on why is this happening?

**Plus**: The console shows *nothing at all*.

Comment: Interesting, but it actually works in a sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/ykwqopn9r1

Comment: @Bsalex It's funny because it's true, but also is that on my project it does not :(

Comment: Removing my answer as i think this is not the correct answer. People can give better answer. I also found it to be working in sandbox